# Drupal 8 Commerce 2 product autocomplete only rendered for admin user accounts

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-commerce

On a fresh install of Drupal 8 with commerce 8.x-2.13 try to use the product autocomplete.
The autocomplete works out of the box for user 1 or any user with administration role, but not for any other role with regular non admin permissions.
For admin the input is rendered as autocomplete, but for any other user it is shown as a regular field.

Even tried to set all permissions to authenticated users but still no autocomplete field rendered for products

Someone to help with what I am missing on my configuration.